# Getting errors while debugging Facebook Pixel microdata

Tags: php, magento2, facebook-opengraph, facebook-pixel

I have already set up the required fields for Facebook Pixel Microdata,

```
<meta property="og:id"
      content="65" />
<meta property="og:availability"
      content="in stock" />

<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title"
      content="iPhone&#x20;12&#x20;Mini&#x20;Leather&#x20;Case&#x20;-&#x20;Black" />
<meta property="og:image"
      content="http://somedomain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/5efc2b204f567b56968e759f077341ad/j/0/j04ai1254bl01_2_1_1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description"
      content="Super&#x20;slim&#x20;profile&#x0D;&#x0A;Compatible&#x20;with&#x20;MagSafe&#x20;and&#x20;Qi&#x20;charging&#x0D;&#x0A;Premium,&#x20;environment&#x20;friendly,&#x20;hydrophobic&#x20;leather&#x0D;&#x0A;Soft&#x20;microfiber&#x20;lining&#x20;and&#x20;rounded&#x20;edges" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://somedomain.com/iphone-12-6-1-inch-german-leather-9.html" />
    <meta property="product:price:amount" content="69.949001"/>
    <meta property="product:price:currency"
      content="AUD"/>
```

But when I debug it in https://business.facebook.com/ it throws error that

```
'A required field is missing: id'
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is `property="product:catalog_id"`.
You can check the detail in facebook official document:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog/reference/#og-tags